# What (spiritual/religious) terms did the Buddha redefine?

Tags: pali, language, three-poisons

It seems a significant and overlooked contribution of the Buddha, his redefining of various terms of his day into definitions more conducive to the ending of greed, ill-will and delusion/ignorance.

What are (all) these redefined terms (if not listed elsewhere)?

Comment: It would be helpful to say some more about where you suspect they might have been redefined from. I'm guessing Hinduism.

Comment: maybe an example as the Buddhist take is different: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niyama

Comment: So you're asking: *what identical words does Buddhism share with Hinduism that have different meanings.* And your looking for a list of those words?

Comment: I think this is too broad, you don't expect to see a complete list in an answer, do you?

Comment: @AndreiVolkov It's atypical but occasionally a Stack Exchange site allows this kind of topic (for example [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/244/1097)).

Comment: Max, yes, words, or termed concepts Buddhism shares with Hinduism but with different meanings. But even more helpful may be such words and terms Buddhism shares with any (major) teaching (systems) that were in significant use during the time of the Buddha. Priority perhaps given to the frequency of such words and terms used by the Buddha and/or the importance the Buddha placed on any of these.

Answer (score 4):

The Buddha redefined the term Brahmin :

> *Yassa pāraṁ apāraṁ vā pārāpāraṁ na vijjati,*
> For whom the near shore,
> the far shore or both do not exist,
>
> *vītaddaraṁ visaṁyuttaṁ, tam-ahaṁ brūmi brāhmaṇaṁ.*
> free of anxiety,
> being detached, that one I say is a brahmin.
> [Dhammapada 385](https://www.ancient-buddhist-texts.net/Texts-and-Translations/Dhammapada/26-Brahmins.htm)

Answer (score 3):

The Buddha redefined the term "*yañña*" (sacrifice), sometimes spelt "*yajna*" or "*yajña*".

The Buddha discouraged animal sacrifice, human sacrifice, and other extra extravagant ritualistic sacrifices (soma juice drinking etc.), of which I quoted only part of the sutta of [AN 4.39](https://suttacentral.net/an4.39/en/sujato) below.

The Buddha however praised non-violent sacrifices, which I think refers to giving gifts (or contributing necessities) to family members.

So, it looks to me like he redefined this term from animal sacrifice to giving charity, which is also supported by [this Pali-English dictionary entry](https://dsal.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/app/pali_query.py?page=547).

A similar teaching is given in [SN 3.9](https://suttacentral.net/sn3.9/en/sujato).

> “Does Master Gotama praise sacrifice (*yañña*)?”
>
> “Brahmin, I don’t praise all sacrifices. Nor do I criticize all
> sacrifices. Take the kind of sacrifice where cattle, goats and sheep,
> chickens and pigs, and various kinds of creatures are slaughtered. I
> criticize that kind of violent sacrifice. Why is that? Because neither
> perfected ones nor those who are on the path to perfection will attend
> such a violent sacrifice.
>
> But take the kind of sacrifice where cattle, goats and sheep, chickens
> and pigs, and various kinds of creatures are not slaughtered. I praise
> that kind of non-violent sacrifice; for example, a regular gift as an
> ongoing family sacrifice. Why is that? Because perfected ones and
> those who are on the path to perfection will attend such a non-violent
> sacrifice.
> [AN 4.39](https://suttacentral.net/an4.39/en/sujato)

---

In [SN 7.21](https://suttacentral.net/sn7.21/en/sujato), the Buddha redefined the ritualistic practice of purification by immersion in water, into purification by immersion in virtues.

In [Sigalovada Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.31.0.ksw0.html), the Buddha redefined the practice of prayer directed in six directions.

Comment: Curious indeed this "ongoing family sacrifice" -- I feel the translation for this has yet to come into its own so to speak/type